# cygwin: timeout syntax always fails

Tags: bash, command, cygwin

With Cygwin, I tried to use "timeout" to make my script sleep for a few seconds.
But even when I did it according to its syntax it always asks me to `try --help`, meaning I gave the wrong forms. 
Here are the things I've tried

```
timeout 5

timeout 5s

timeout 5.0s

timeout 5.
```

None of which worked.

Any ideas?!

Comment: If you want your script to sleep, you want `sleep(1)`.  Why are you trying to use timeout?  Besides that, it's telling you to check `timeout --help` which clearly states you need to also give a command to it.

Comment: I made a mistake. I think what I wanted was the dos timeout, not the cygwin one. Which uses simply this syntax: timeout <seconds>. Anyways, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think `timeout` does what you think it does.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout):

> timeout [OPTION] NUMBER[SUFFIX] COMMAND [ARG]...
>
> Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after NUMBER seconds. SUFFIX may be 's' for seconds (the default), 'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days.

You need to give it that command.  Here's a simple example:

```
$ date; timeout 5 sleep 10; date
Thu, Nov 01, 2012  3:19:28 PM
Thu, Nov 01, 2012  3:19:33 PM
```

As you can see, only 5 seconds elapsed even though I ran `sleep 10`.  That's because it timed out after 5 seconds and the `timeout` command killed it.